# Select rows with one or another condition or both combined

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table like this:

```
Name   Candy   Fruits
_____________________
John     1        2
Luis     0        1
Mary     1        1
Julio    0        0
```

What I'm trying to do is to filter this information, the people who has just candy: `John, Mary`.
Or just the people who has fruits: `John, Luis, Mary`

What I have tried is this:

```
DECLARE @wCandy BIT, @wFruits BIT
SET @wCandy = 1, @wFruits = 0

SELECT Name, Candy, Fruits 
  FROM People
 WHERE (
         (@wCandy = 0) OR (Candy > 0))
         AND ((@wFruits = 0) OR (Fruits > 0))
       )
```

Which result in this (just the people woth more than 0 candy):

```
Name   Candy   Fruits
_____________________
John     1        2
Mary     1        1
```

So if I set `@wCandy = 0` and `@wFruits = 1` I should see the people with more than 0 fruits and viceversa with `@wCandy` set to 1

That works, but there's another case when I want both, the ones with candy and fruits. The result should be:

```
Name   Candy   Fruits
_____________________
John     1        2
Luis     0        1
Mary     1        1
```

I have tried so many things like using CASE statement but I have not gotten it to work. I hope someone can help.

Comment: It is not clear what the issue is here. Are you only setting your candy variable and not setting the fruits variable? If so, your fruits variable will be NULL and will not be returned.

Comment: @SeanLange uh, sorry. See my edit please!

Comment: To cover all cases you should add a user that has Candy and not has Fruits.

Answer (score 0):

If you need all users that have Candy + all users that have Fruits + all users that have Candy and Fruits, use a UNION:

```
SELECT Name, Candy, Fruits FROM People WHERE Candy > 0
UNION
SELECT Name, Candy, Fruits FROM People WHERE Fruits > 0
UNION
SELECT Name, Candy, Fruits FROM People WHERE Fruits > 0 AND Candy > 0

+------+-------+--------+
| Name | Candy | Fruits |
+------+-------+--------+
| John |   1   |    2   |
+------+-------+--------+
| Luis |   0   |    1   |
+------+-------+--------+
| Mary |   1   |    1   |
+------+-------+--------+
```

Check it here: http://rextester.com/VHMV68063

Comment: Yeah but I need the three different cases! 1: just the ones with fruits, 2: just the ones with candy, 3: candy + fruits

Comment: UNION has an implicit DISTINCT

Comment: By definition the third query here is redundant. You have all people that have Candy > 0, then you have all people that have Fruit > 0. The third set is already included in the first two. There is no chance that the third query can return a person that was not already part of either of the first two.

Comment: @SeanLange yes I know, initially there was two, I've added another one to show the OP that nothing changes. Look at comments

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing, given the other answers you've received and your responses...
Do you mean something like this?

```
    SELECT P.Name, P.Candy, P.Fruits 
    FROM People P
    WHERE 
        (
            (
            @wCandy = 1
            AND P.Candy >= 1
            )
            OR
            (
            @wCandy = 0
            AND P.Candy = 0
            )
        )
        AND 
        (
            (
            @wFruits = 1
            AND P.Fruits >= 1
            )
            OR
            (
            @wFruits = 0
            AND P.Fruits = 0
            )
        )
;
```

This gives you the proper filter no matter what conditions you input...

1. People with just candy
2. People with just fruit
3. People with fruit and candy
4. People with no fruit and no candy